# Pytest: No module named 'src' when run tests from command line

Tags: python, pytest

So I have `python` project and several tests with `pytest`.

This is my project hierarchy:

```
project_name
  src
    managers
      config_manager.py (with ConfigManager class inside)
    tests
      api_tests.py
  config.ini
```

**api_tests.py**

```
from src.managers.config_manager import ConfigManager

def test_foo():
   print('tests tarted')
```

So when the test run from my `pycharm` ide my click on run button all works fine but when I start the test using terminal I got this error:

> ```
> from src.managers.config_manager import ConfigManager
> E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
> ```

Of course if this line comment out the test can execute.
Any suggestion what could cause this and how to fix it ?

Comment: do you have a `__init__.py` in src and the sub folders?

Comment: no, I dont have this files

Comment: I added this files and still this error

Comment: Did you add one to the tests folder?
Also, I would put the tests folder at the same level as the src directory and not in it, but that is a personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

The reason:

> The interpreter doesn't know where to look for your module / package

Why does this work using `PyCharm`? Because `PyCharm` automatically resolves paths. You can find options `add content roots to PYTHONPATH` and `add content source roots to PYTHONPATH` in settings.

How to run tests using terminal? Files content:

```
# src/managers/config_manager.py
class ConfigManager:
    @staticmethod
    def get_config() -> dict:
        return dict(parsed='config')

# src/tests/api_tests.py
from src.managers.config_manager import ConfigManager
def test_get_config():
    print(ConfigManager.get_config())
```

Open terminal:

```
cd project_name
tree
# Example structure. Result:
# ── src
#    ├── managers
#    │   ├── config_manager.py
#    │   └── __init__.py
#    └── tests
#        └── api_tests.py

export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:${pwd}/src/"
pytest src/tests/*
# =================================================================== test session starts ===================================================================
# platform linux -- Python 3.10.6, pytest-7.2.1, pluggy-1.0.0
# rootdir: /home/d_ganchar/PycharmProjects/project_name
# collected 1 item                                                                                                                                          
# src/tests/api_tests.py .                                                                                                                            [100%]
# ==================================================================== 1 passed in 0.00s ====================================================================
```

Also you can try to use [pytest-srcpaths](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-srcpaths/) or [tox](https://tox.wiki/en/latest/)